# Data substitution in shell using awk & gsub?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, gnu

I want to write a script to substitute data in a customer master extract. Read from a datafile and search for equivalences in the CM extract(inputfile), once found substitute those records in inputfile.
Substitution is basically **replace alternate characters with a certain symbol** , lets say **$**

I need help to write a shell script based on this algorithm!
Apologies for not being to the point with my post. I still learning to be a better SO user. :)

**datafile**

```
User
User Jason
User Jason Derek
AlbertEinstein 
Albert
/Customer
User Jason Derek
JPM.Co
```

**inputfile**

```
<td>User </td>
 <td>User Jason </td>
 <td>JPM.Co</td>
<td></td>
 <td>User Jason Derek</td>
 <td>AlbertEinstein</td>
 <td>Albert</td>
 <td>/Customer</td>
 <td>User Jason Derek</td>
</tr>
```

**required op:-**

```
<td>U$e$</td>
 <td>U$e$ J$s$n</td>
 <td>J$M.$o</td>
<td></td>
 <td>U$e$ J$s$n D$r$k</td>
 <td>A$b$r$E$n$t$I$</td>
 <td>A$b$r$</td>
 <td>/$u$t$m$</td>
 <td>U$e$ J$s$n D$r$k</td>
</tr>
```

I actually tried writing the code but its not working. Too embarrassed to be posting it here, but here goes.

```
awk ' FNR==NR
{
if ($0 in datafile)
next
datafile[$0]=$0
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
 {
   a=$i
   b=""
   len=length(a)
   for (j=1; j<=len; j++) {
    c = c (j%2==1? substr(a,j,1): "$")
  }
print 
}' datafile extract
```

I m stuck here, don't know how to proceed. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Great! `FNR==NR{` this block only runs for `datafile`. You have to do two blocks, for two files `FNR==NR{ <remmber datafile in an arary >}   FNR!=NR{ <search & replace here> }`

Comment: the `awk` solution (in the referenced duplicate) replaces every 3-letter sequence with `#` in the 2nd/3rd positions ... should be easy enough to modify for this requirement